# Algorithm to make groups of units

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, strategy

In Age of Mythology and some other strategy games, when you select multiple units and order them to move to some place, they make a "group" when they reach the desired location:

[image: Group]

I have a Vector with several sprites, which are the selected units, the variables `tarX` and `tarY` are the target x and y. I just want an example, so you can just set the x and y position and I can adapt it to my code. Also, I would like to ask that the algorithm calls "isWalkable" for the x and y position, to determine if it's a valid position for each unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is basically coordinated movement. The units pathfind to their destination and when they reach it, they form a "formation".

This is a topic decently covered in the AI Game Programming Wisdom ([Book 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584500778), [Book 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584502894), [Book 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584504579) and [Book 4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584505230)) books. But, I'll refer you to the following articles:

[Coordinated Movement](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3313/coordinated_unit_movement.php) - A link explaining the fundamental principles of coordinated unit movement in RTS games

and

[Implementing Coordinated Movement](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3314/implementing_coordinated_movement.php) - An article continuing from the first, that talks about how to implement this type of movement in a game.

It's written in C++ but it shouldn't be too difficult to port to any other language, as the underlying principles remain the same.

Hope that helps.

Ray

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna read it. I am using A* path finding.